# How to turn Spring @Autowired required property to false for test?

Tags: java, spring, testing, dependency-injection

I've been using the @Required annotation up to now to ensure DI of my beans in a Spring configured application.

To enable the annotation, you need to declare a RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor bean in your configuration.

In your test configuration you just don't declare it, so that if some beans are not needed you don't have to have them in your config.

I want to switch to less XML and use @Autowired annotation, but it is by default required=true, which is fine for the runtime configuration.

But I need @Autowired to be required=false for testing purpose only - while keeping it required for runtime.

Is that possible at all? I can't find a way to declaratively turn the required property to false.

cheers

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You probably solved it already but this trick might be useful for others.

As far as I understood without *context:annotation-driven* being present @Autowired annotations should not be processed but this is clearly not the case so I might misunderstood something.

However, I needed a quick solution... This somewhat dirty trick negates required value for all classes making optional what was required before. Adding it to my *test context* solved my problem but it is useful only if all autowirings are required in your business classes.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor">
    <property name="requiredParameterValue" value="false" />
</bean>
```

Comment: A precision: to get this working, it has to be placed prior to <context:annotation-config />, otherwise it won't be taken into account.

Answer (score 7):

I worked out a solution that works for JavaConfig configurations

```java
@ContextConfiguration(initializers={DisableAutowireRequireInitializer.class})
public class TestCase {
    // Some tests
}
```

```java
public class DisableAutowireRequireInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

@Override
public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {

    // Register the AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor while initalizing
    // the context so we get there before any @Autowire resolution happens
    // We set the "requiredParameterValue" so that @Autowire fields are not 
    // required to be resolved. Very useful for a test context
    GenericApplicationContext ctx = (GenericApplicationContext) applicationContext;
    ctx.registerBeanDefinition(AnnotationConfigUtils.AUTOWIRED_ANNOTATION_PROCESSOR_BEAN_NAME,
            BeanDefinitionBuilder
                .rootBeanDefinition(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.class)
                .addPropertyValue("requiredParameterValue", false)
                .getBeanDefinition());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same technique as you did with `@Required` - don't register the `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` in your test context, but leave it in your live context.

This is usually registered by adding `<context:annotation-driven/>`, rather than being declared manually.

Comment: Wait a minute, if you don't add the <context:annotation-config />, Spring doesn't even detect the @Autowired annotation, right?

What I'd like, ideally, but I'm sure many have faced the problem, is to have Spring load the <context:annotation-config />, i-e detect annotations, but turn the default @Autowired(required = true) to false, so that I don't have to inject dependencies that are required at runtime but not useful, or even not welcome, in test mode.

Comment: @nodje: Fair enough, but that's not how it works, I'm afraid.