# how can I inject "nulls" into autowired spring beans?

Tags: spring, junit, mockito

I am writing unit-tests and have a quite complex setting.

A dependent bean sets up some listeners and passes them autowired services.

I want to test that the listeners are present, but not call them, so I want to pass 'null' instead of the autowired service. (specifically: I do not have setters ...)

```
@Autowired
SomeService1 service1

@Autowired
SomeService2 service2


public List getListeners() {
  List l = new ArrayList();
  l.add(new AaaListener(service1));
  l.add(new BbbListener(Service2));
  return l;
}
```

---

```
@Test
public void testListeners() {
  int exptecedSize = 2;

  sut.doSomething();

  List l = sut.getX().getY().getListeners()

  assertEquals(expectedSize,l.size());
}
```

Note that the SUT does depend indirectly from the class that returns the listeners.

Since this is a very small example from a big setting, I do specifically **do not want to use mocks** here as I want to test only presence not behavior of the listeners.

Mocking 20 or 30 of such services will slow down the tests massively.

**Question: What is the easiest way to inject these nulls into the autowired instance variables?**

A) Add setters ?

B) ReflectionUtils ?

C) java-config + @Beans + return null ?

Comment: question answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279868/how-to-turn-spring-autowired-required-property-to-false-for-test

Answer (score 1):

They're already `null` when the class is instantiated ... or are you actually running them in a spring context?

You can set properties to null in the xml config like this (from the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html))

```
<bean class="ExampleBean">
    <property name="email"><null/></property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Yes, they are in an autowired spring context. I have roughly 100 Beans to setup manually for the test and I do not get a grip on it. I am quite reluctant to write a spring.xml from ground-up ...

Comment: Why can't you just have them injected with whatever implementation exists?

Comment: it's too big: hundreds of spring.xmls, thousands of beans, mixed architectural styles ... :-/

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use the Spring context and create the class manually
2. Use `ReflectionTestUtils` to set the field. `ReflectionTestUtils` allows for the setting of private fields where `ReflectionUtils` does not.