# Assertion error expected 500 but got 400 Junit testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, testcase

Controller:

```
@ApiOperation(value = " update record", response = APIResponse.class)
@ApiResponses(value = {@ApiResponse(code =200, message = "OK"),
@ApiResponses(value = {@ApiResponse(code =500, message = "Internal server error"),
@ApiResponses(value = {@ApiResponse(code =404, message = "NO_RECORD")})
@PutMapping(value = "/update/{id}")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<APIResponse> updateRecord(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody RecordDTO input, @PathVariable(value="id") int code){
APIResponse response = null;
try{
   response = service.updateRecord(code, input);
}
  catch(JSONException e){
  log.error("Error Parsing JSON");
  response = new APIResponse(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, ERROR_JSON_PARSING, ERROR);
}
return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

my test case foor controller:

```
@Test
public void update() throws Exception{
   RecordDTO recordDto = new RecordDTO();
   Object mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   String value = mapper.writeValueAsString(StationDTO);

given(service.updateRecord(anyInt(), any(RecordDTO.class))).willThrow(JSONException.class);
mockMvc.perform(put(baseUrl + "/update/12")
.contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(value))
.andExpect(status().isInternalservererror())
.andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.status",Matchers.is("INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR")))
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.message",Matchers.is("ERROR_JSON_PARSING")))
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.resposeStatus",Matchers.is("ERROR")));

APIResponse response = new APIResponse(HttpStatus.OK, SUCCESS, SUCCESS, null);
given(service.updateRecord(anyInt(), any(RecordDTO.class))).willReturn(response);
mockMvc.perform(put(baseUrl + "/update/12")
.contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(value))
.andExpect(status().isOk())
.andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.status",Matchers.is("OK")))
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.message",Matchers.is("SUCCESS")))
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.resposeStatus",Matchers.is("SUCCESS")));
}
```

DTO:

```
public class RecordDTO{
private String id;
private String name;
private String number;
}
```

I am getting java.lang assertion error expected 500 but was 200. I don't what is wrong with the test case.. Is there any other way to write the test case? Also can you recommend any platform from where i can gain knowledge of how to write test cases then do comment down. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your mocked `service` is not injecting into your controller.

Alternative solution (I assume you use Spring-Boot):

1. [DisableAutowireRequireInitializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279868/how-to-turn-spring-autowired-required-property-to-false-for-test). This will prevent to load all dependencies inside your Controller.
2. Create inside your ControllerTest inner class: `private static ServiceImplMock entends ServiceImpl`
3. Now, override `updateRecord` method inside `ServiceMock` to do your testing cases

---

```
@Override
public APIResponse updateRecord(int code, RecordDTO input) throws JSONException {
    if(code == 12) throw new JSONException(...)
    else your_business_logic
}
```

4. Now, add this `ServiceImplMock` into your `@SpringBootTest`

---

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {
    Controller.class,
    ControllerTest.ServiceImplMock.class,
    ...
})
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ContextConfiguration( initializers = {DisableAutowireRequireInitializer.class })
class ControllerTest {
```

5. Now, your test cases should work (Remove `given(...).willThrow(...);` since we don't need it anymore)

> Also can you recommend any platform from where i can gain knowledge of how to write test cases then do comment down

https://www.baeldung.com/junit 
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing 
https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-junit-5-mockito/